# How to make a php crawler to search particular string?

Tags: php

How can I create a crawler in php which search for a particular string in a webpage and returns whether it is present or not?

Comment: Before posting question you should have tried something so that we can assist with...

Comment: Try posting some code that you're unable to proceed with. The community here helps with issues more than with concepts alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function I made, it takes in the pages URL and the string to look for in this URL's content.

```
<?php
var_dump(searchPage("http://google.com", "Tacos")); //False
var_dump(searchPage("http://google.com", "Google")); //True

function searchPage($url, $string){
    $input = file_get_contents($url);
    if (strpos($input,$string) !== false) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

I hope this helped,
Sebastian